# Maven compile error "cannot find symbol" after any change to one project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

Well iam learning JEE with maven in the same time :p
i have this structure of projects in netbeans
->core
->frontoffice

frontoffice uses classes from core so i've added dependency in pom.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.directmedia.onlinestore</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontoffice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>frontoffice</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>m.directmedia.onlinestore</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

core project pom.xml not changes.
every thing works fine i can use classes of core project in frontoffice, however when i add something to core classes and clean & build.. OK but when i do clean & build on frontoffice project i got error of what i've added :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[79,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable aa
  location: variable titre1 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[80,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable aa
  location: variable titre2 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[81,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable aa
  location: variable titre3 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[101,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable aa
  location: variable oeuvre of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
4 errors 
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.899 s
Finished at: 2019-10-14T22:19:21+02:00
Final Memory: 17M/196M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project frontoffice: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[79,15] cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable aa
location: variable titre1 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[80,15] cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable aa
location: variable titre2 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[81,15] cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable aa
location: variable titre3 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[101,27] cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable aa
location: variable oeuvre of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

It's like the old version of classes still there and the compiler compile them not the modified ones.
i've tried to clean project and netbeans cache but the same errors i don't know why this happen it seems to me illogic.

Can you help me to figure out what is the problem ?

To see my code and test that here is the repository : https://github.com/AmineJonahi/jee.maven

Comment: Once a project is installed with a non-snapshot version, it's not supposed to change anymore. That's what allows Maven to avoid redownloading all your dependencies every time you compile. You should have a lulti-module project, not independant projects like this. ANd if core is supposed to be a library, its packaging shouldn't be war, but jar.

Comment: I have tried transformingboth projects to SNAPSHOT in pom.xml in order to let maven redownload libraries but didn't work always "Cannot find symbol on the modification i did to code the aa variable even it is known in auto completion", i have also change packaging type for the core project to jar but didn't work too. I know the multi module system but even with this configuration it should work and i have disabled automatic build too but not working always the same error

Comment: here is one of the errors : com/directmedia/onlinestore/controller/CatalogueServlet.java:[79,15] cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable aa
location: variable titre1 of type com.directmedia.onlinestore.core.entity.Work

the variable aa is what i have add to Work classe in core project, if i delete the modification all things work fine but why i can't add anything to my core classes ?